# Show that $ A_G \simeq \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}A $ for $G$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I found this ring theory exercise in an algebra textbook.  Let $G$ be a group and then $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is a [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) and let $A$ be a $G$-module.
$$ A_G \simeq \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}A $$
Here the group of

- $G$-invariants is: $ A^G = \{ a \in A  : g \cdot A = a \text{ for all } g\in G, a \in A\} $
- $G$-[coinvariants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#coinvariants) is $A_G = A/I_G A$ the part of $A$ that is fixed by $G$

The Wikipedia article on [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) has a lot of discussion but also some warnings, so there is also the [article](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00CV) on Stacks Project.

Comment: Have you encountered modules and tensor products before? If not, this is probably not the best jumping off point.

Comment: hello! were you able to understand either my or reuns' answer below? if not, please feel free to ask any questions you may have! otherwise, it would be appreciated if you could accept either of the answers, to get the question off the unanswered queue. thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Credit to Shivering Soldier for pointing out the cleaner argument given below.

---

Lemma: For any ring $R$, ideal $I\leqslant R$, and left $R$-module $M$, we have $M\big/IM\cong R/I\otimes_R M$.

Proof: Define a map $\phi:M\rightarrow R/I\otimes_RM$ by $m\mapsto (1+I)\otimes m$. That $\phi$ is a morphism of abelian groups is immediate from the definition of the tensor product; indeed, for $m,n\in M$, we have $$\phi(m-n)=(1+I)\otimes(m-n)=(1+I)\otimes m-(1+I)\otimes n,$$ as needed. Furthermore, for any $i\in I$ and $m\in M$, we have $$\phi(i\cdot m)=(1+I)\otimes i\cdot m=(1+I)\cdot i\otimes m=(i+I)\otimes m=(0+I)\otimes m=0,$$ so $IM\subseteq\ker{\phi}$ and hence $\phi$ descends to a map $\overline\phi:M\big/IM\rightarrow R/I\otimes_R M$.

We now define $\overline\psi:R/I\otimes_R M\rightarrow M\big/IM$, an inverse to $\overline\phi$, via the universal property of tensor products. First define $\psi:R/I\times M\rightarrow M\big/IM$ by $(r+I,m)\mapsto rm+IM$. To see that this is well-defined, note that $\psi(i+I,m)=im+IM=0+IM$ for any $i\in I$, as needed. $\psi$ is clearly additive in each variable, and we claim that it is $R$-balanced. Indeed, for $x\in R$, $r+I\in R\big/I$, and $m\in M$, we have $$\psi((r+I)\cdot x,m)=\psi(rx+I,m)=rxm+IM=\psi(r+I,x\cdot m),$$ as desired.

Thus $\psi$ descends to a group homomorphism $\overline\psi:R/I\otimes_R M\rightarrow M\big/IM$. We claim now that $\overline\psi$ and $\overline\phi$ are mutual inverses. To see that $\overline\psi\circ\overline\phi=\operatorname{id}_{M/IM}$, let $m\in M$. Then $$\overline\psi(\overline\phi(m+IM))=\overline\psi((1+I)\otimes m)=1m+IM=m+IM,$$ as desired. To see that $\overline\phi\circ\overline\psi=\operatorname{id}_{R/I\otimes M}$, it suffices to show that it acts as the identity on simple tensors. Thus let $r+I\in R\big/I$ and $m\in M$. We have $\overline\psi((r+I)\otimes m)=rm+IM$, and $$\overline\phi(rm+IM)=(1+I)\otimes r\cdot m=(1+I)\cdot r\otimes m=(r+I)\otimes m,$$ again as desired. Hence $\overline\phi$ and $\overline\psi$ are mutual inverses and so we have the desired isomorphism.

---

The result you desire is now an immediate corollary of the above lemma. Just to make all notation clear: $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} A$ is an abelian group, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is considered as a (right) $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module on which every $g\in G$ acts as the identity. We can define $\iota:\mathbb{Z}[G]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$, the "augmentation map", by extending $g\mapsto 1$ linearly for each $g\in G$. Then $I_G$, the "augmentation ideal", is defined to be $\ker{\iota}$, and $A_G:=A\big/I_GA$.

Note that $\iota$ is in fact surjective (for instance, $\iota(n1_G)=n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $1_G\in G$ is the identity element). Thus, by the first isomorphism theorem, we have $\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}[G]\big/I_G$. This induces the chain of isomorphisms $$\mathbb{Z}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} A\cong\mathbb{Z}[G]/I_G\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}A\cong A\big/I_GA,$$ where the second isomorphism follows from the lemma above, and this gives the desired result.

Comment: Nice exposition!

Comment: @darijgrinberg thank you! that's very kind of you to say :) (thank you for the edits also.) I've seen a number of your answers on here and always very much enjoy/learn from them!

Comment: Can I know what is the problem with mine ? @darijgrinberg

Comment: I have seen a proof of this where they write $\Bbb Z $ as $\Bbb Z[G]/I_G $ and then use the isomorphism  $(R/I)\otimes_R M\cong M/IM$. I'm not entirely sure about it's validity though. (+1)

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier oh nice, that argument is very clean! I guess the "spirit" of the proofs is similar because the isomorphisms wind up looking essentially the same, but your way is cleaner/avoids a few of the computations... thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier I've replaced the original argument with yours; hope that's alright!

Comment: @reuns I just don't think it has enough detail for the OP, based on my guess how much he has worked with tensors.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb{Z}$ is a $\Bbb{Z}[G]$ module through $g.n=n$

$A\to \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}A$ is surjective

$1\otimes g.a=g.1\otimes a=1\otimes a$ so

$$\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}A\cong \mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}(A/I_GA)$$

where $I_G=\{ \sum n_g g\in \Bbb{Z}[G], \sum n_g=0\}$ is the two-sided ideal generated by the $1-g$.

Clearly since $g$ acts trivially on $A/I_GA$ $$\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}(A/I_GA)\cong A/I_GA$$

Comment: So it was just saying that $(\mathbb{Z}[G]/I_G) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]}A\cong A/I_G A$

Comment: For a finite group $|G|=e$ if $A$ was a $\Bbb{Z}[e^{-1}]$ module then $A/I_GA \cong A^G$